# Logging decoded response body with Kong

Tags: python, kong, kong-plugin

I'm using kong in declarative db-less mode, my setup is similar to

```
services:
- name: dummy
  url: <url>
  routes:
    - name: dummy-route
      hosts:
        - <host>
      paths:
        - /dummy

plugins:
- name: pre-function
  config:
      body_filter:
        - kong.log.set_serialize_value("response.body", kong.service.response.get_raw_body())
      access:
        - kong.service.request.enable_buffering()
- name: file-log
  config:
      path: /usr/local/kong/logs.txt
      reopen: true
```

I have a simple route and I want to log the response body, this setup works but I want to save the body in a readable format. In this way the saved response looks like:
[image]
(printed by a python console)

and as text something like:

```
\u001f \b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002 }RAn 0\u0010  \u001
```

I saw Kong gives a method to get a decoded response `kong.service.response.get_body(<mimetype>)`, I've tried with `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` and `"application/json"` mimetypes. The first gives the same result as the `get_raw_body()` method, the other gives `null`.

The content-type of the response is "application/json", in general I was expecting to be able to log the message of the server response using log but seems really difficult.

Comment: What is the value of `Content-Encoding:` ?

Comment: @Ôrel  In the response section 'content-encoding': 'gzip'

Comment: So I think this is gzip encoded